# Make ecryptfs work on kerberos secured nfs4-share

Tags: linux, encryption, nfs, kerberos, ecryptfs

I have a working single-signe-on setup using Kerberos and openLDAP. I have setup NFS4 to use this infrastructure to control access to the shared folders. This works perfectly fine. The NFS4 sever serves the home-dirs for the users on the network. At the moment I am trying to set up encrypted home folders for all my users. This is where it gets messy.

Since I am unable to access a kerberized nfs4 share with root privilege (no_root_squash does not work) the ecryptfs-migrate-home script is does not work. I am looking for a way to work around this. My first idea was to leave the client out of this matter and do the encryption setup directly on the server. The problem here is that folders are stored in /nfs4share/home. So running the migration script on the server wouldn't work. The prompt for the user password by the script fails anyways. (I think it can't deal with the Kerberos/LDAP-auth). The servers involved all run on Debian Wheezy, the majority of the clients run Linux Mint Debian Edition. If further information is needed I'll be happy to provide it.

Does anyone know how to do this setup manually, so I can export it via NFS4?

Any help is greatly appreciated.